# Can't finish icinga2 set-up via web wizard

Tags: icinga2

I've been installing Icinga2 on my openSUSE Tumbleweed system with following package versions:

- icinga2-2.10.1-2.1.x86_64
- php7-7.2.11-1.3.src

and I'm stuck on the following web site of the setup wizard:
[image]

When I click on button Next, there's no action hapening.
I've checked Network and Console of the browser and there's no error. Similarly in a different browser.

Comment: Personally, I would click the button labeled "Next".

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I clicked Next (post updated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in icingaweb2 2.6.2 version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the warnings on the right side (e.g. missing the LDAP module) are actually errors, and you can click `Next` once they are resolved (i.e. packages installed via zypper).

Comment: I don't think so, e.g. there's a video where not all are green: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-6ZlKADU4M. If it would require all to have green, I would expect from user interface to make it clear to user.